# Push a state in react-navigation without refreshing screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have an app using React Navigation where I need to be able to do the following:

- Cause an automatic state transition, without reloading the current screen (e.g. by changing a param)
- Be able to use the 'back' button to reverse this transition

This is complicated by the fact that I'm using a `StackNavigator` nested inside a `TabNavigator`: the usual approach to handling an internal action like this would be to simply listen on the back button event (registering the event in `componentDidMount` and removing it in `componentWillUnmount`), but unfortunately when I do that, my handler *also* triggers when other tabs are open, which is confusing for the user.

I've tried using `navigation.setState`, but when I use this it doesn't add anything to the navigation stack so the state change can't be undone by pressing the back button.

I've also tried using `navigation.push`, but that causes a new instance of my screen to be created with different component states, and the transition is visible, which just doesn't work.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You should still consider handling this internal action in its own view. But `navigation. addListener` may not be suitable here. Instead you should replace the back button component in the header with your own one and add your own `onPress` prop.

Example:

```
import {
  HeaderBackButton
} from 'react-navigation'

class MyComponent extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const params = navigation.state.params

    class BackButton extends React.Component {
      goBack = () => {
        if (params.isInternalGoBack) {
          // do some internal goback action
        } else {
          this.props.onPress() // original Back button behavior
        }
      }
      render () {
        return (
          <HeaderBackButton {...this.props} onPress={this.goBack} />
        )
      }
    }

    return {
      headerLeft: BackButton
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Then you can use `this.props.navigation.setParams({ isInternalGoBack: true })` to control back button behavior.

Comment: How would I handle the hardware back button in this scheme?  My main problem is that I don't know how to prevent it triggering when the screen in question isn't currently visible.

Comment: agree, this a decent hackaround, but if it doesn't work with the hardware back button it's not really enough

Comment: @Jules did you find a better workaround ?, I'm facing the exact same use case and wondering how to solve it with react-navigation

Comment: @tdurand - no; not long after posting this question the client asked for a user interface redesign for the app in question that meant it was no longer necessary.

Comment: @Jules thanks, I gonna do something like this and also hook this plugin to handle back button: https://github.com/vonovak/react-navigation-backhandler  .. not gonna be super pretty but should work...